# How to read a single BIT in an Array of Bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, byte, bit

The problem is that I have an Array of Byte with 200 Indexes and just want to check that is the Fourth bit of MyArray[75] is Zero(0) or One(1).

```
byte[] MyArray; //with 200 elements

//check the fourth BIT of  MyArray[75]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the fourth bit?" Bit 3 or bit 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fourth bit in element 75?

```
if((MyArray[75] & 8) > 0) // bit is on
else // bit is off
```

The & operator allows you to use a value as a mask.

```
xxxxxxxx = ?
00001000 = 8 &
----------------
0000?000 = 0 | 8
```

You can use this method to gather any of the bit values using the same technique.

```
1   = 00000001
2   = 00000010
4   = 00000100
8   = 00001000
16  = 00010000
32  = 00100000
64  = 01000000
128 = 10000000
```

Comment: Actually 8 would be the 3rd bit

Comment: bit 3 is the fourth bit :) (bit 0 is the first bit)

Comment: Well, that all depends on what he means by the "fourth bit," doesn't it? :-)

Comment: @ssg, then what's the zeroth bit?

Comment: Yes, my bad (-: Edited my own aswer as well.

Comment: No, 8 is the fourth bit from the least significant end. Or the fifth, if you want to count from the most significant end.

Comment: Given that he's asking this question it's a pretty safe assumption that he's not using the term zeroth bit. Either way, I think he'll have enough information to figure out the answer to his question. ;)

Comment: It's really hard to say. When he's figuring out which bit to look at in which byte, he may very well come up with a bit 0. Just goes to show you how a fuzzy question can ruin yuor day.

Comment: I'im afraid the whole society can split up to little endians and big endians, arguing over if there is really a "zeroth" bit :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
if ( (MyArray[75] & (1 << 3)) != 0)
{
   // it was a 1
}
```

Assuming you meant 4th bit from the right.

And you might want to check out `System.Collections.BitArray`, just to be sure you're not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Or maybe 1<<3, depending on what he meant by 4th bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private bool BitCheck(byte b, int pos)
    {
        return (b & (1 << (pos-1))) > 0;
    }
```

Comment: You keep using that ^ operator. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: ^ is bitwise exclusive-or not power

Comment: I think what Tyler means is you might be looking for the `1 << (pos-1)` statement for 1-indexed positions, or the `1 << pos` statement for 0-indexed positions

Comment: I made mpbloch's substitution and canceled the down vote. Tank seems to be new here so I thought I'd take the liberty.